# Error when accessing sqlite db from xamarin

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I am a newbie in xamarin. Trying to build a login page but when accessing a connection to sqlite error is occurred. Object variable not set to an instance of an object.

```
_SQLiteConnection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteInterface>().GetSQLiteConnection();
```

This is the line which shows error

I made a ISQLiteConnection Interface

```
public interface ISQLiteConnection
{
    SQLiteConnection GetSQLiteConnection();
}
```

This is how I implement ISQLiteConnection

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(GetSQLiteConnnection))]
namespace SqliteLoginDemo.Droid.Dependencies
{
    public class GetSQLiteConnnection : ISQLiteConnection
    {
        public SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection GetSQLiteConnection()
        {
            var fileName = "UserDatabase.db3";
            var documentPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var path = Path.Combine(documentPath, fileName);
            var platform = new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid();
            var connection = new SQLiteConnection(platform, path);
            return connection;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/database?pivots=windows).  Using `DependencyService` is an older approach that is no longer necessary

Comment: You may also refer to [Xamarin.Forms Local Databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases).

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Object variable not set to an instance of an object" usually occurs when you try to access a method or property on an object that is currently `null` or not initialized. I think in your case, the error is likely occurring because the `DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteInterface>()` call is returning `null`, and then you're trying to call the `GetSQLiteConnection()` method on a null object.

Ensure that you have a proper implementation of `ISQLiteInterface`. For example, in your project, you should have a class that implements `ISQLiteInterface` and provides the implementation for `GetSQLiteConnection()`.

```
public class SQLiteInterface : ISQLiteInterface
{
    public SQLiteConnection GetSQLiteConnection()
    {
        // Implement the connection logic here and return the SQLiteConnection object
    }
}
```